# Brainbow fluorescence labeling technique

Tags: genetics

I have this picture describing the Brainbow system here:

[image]

The paper I am reading says it uses Cre-lox recombination to express a certain color. If the cell in question was expressing a yellow fluorescence then what would the construct in that cell look like in terms of the picture given? Would it just be a single line with the UAS, EGFP, and mKO2 in that order or would it be two lines, wone with the UAS and EGFP and on with the UAS and mKO2?

Comment: I would suggest to also read the original Brainbow paper by Livet and colleagues, which goes in details in the genetics of the system and its variations. [Transgenic strategies for combinatorial expression of fluorescent proteins in the nervous system](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17972876) - Livet et al., Nature 2007

Answer (score 1):

Yellow would need the expression of red and green so that would mean the excision of the blue fluorophore. It would be one line with egfp and the other line with mKO2--- the order doesn't matter-- these represent chromosomes.

Comment: In the line expressing green wouldn't you have to excise the blue and red regions as well in stead of just the blue? Similarly for the line expressing red wouldn't you have to excise the green and blue regions? And also what about the STOP cassette?